# Is it possible to implement a split view for ipads by using existing view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ios9.3

I'm building an universal app. I have already created two view controllers.in `first view controller` there is a search from and when user entered the data and hit the `search` button in the `second view controller` it shows the results.now what I want is to create a split view using these two views.

1. Is it possibel? if it is posstible how can I do that and can we implement it only for portrait mode.(without landscape mode).
2. Do we have to use a `tableview` as master view each and every time when we create a split view ?

hope your help with this.thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

UISplitViewController does pretty much everything you ask.  If there is enough space it will display your view controllers side-by-side (see the preferredDisplayMode property).  If you really want to force a side-by-side view controller arrangement in a confined space (ie. portrait), which is probably not advisable from a UX perspective, then you will need to write your own custom split view controller.  Just layout 2 view controllers inside a parent view controller side-by-side and give each of them equal widths.

Also, you do not have to use a UITableView for your master view in a UISplitViewController.  Each view controller in completely customizable.

Comment: are there any tutorials about implement this.

Comment: @AnuradhS Apple's WWDC talks & docs are a great place to start, thanks to able code in slides and full sample projects.  These searches should be plenty to get you started: http://asciiwwdc.com/search?q=UISplitViewController https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=UISplitViewController